# Как сделать так, чтобы страница отдавала код HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found?

Tags: http-status-code-404

Здравствуйте! Создаю страницу 404 на dle. Переадресацию на страницу настроила, прописала в файле 404.html код

```
<body>

 <?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>

</body>
```

- чтобы заголовок отдавал код 404, но сервер отдает код 200 (хотя страница на сайте не существует) вот скриншот результата https://prnt.sc/h0h4un - скажите, что я могла сделать не так? Что сделать, чтобы страница 404 отдавала код HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header() надо использовать до всякого вывода. В данном случае перед body (всяким выводом считаются пробелы и пустые строки так же).